# Avoid Two way binding between objects in C#

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

When i assign a value of a class object to other class object and when i change a property of 1st object it reflects in other object.

Example:
class A has property of type int Aid

SelectedA is a property of a Viewmodel Class which is binded to A WPF View.
SelectedA.Aid is in TwoWay binding with a combo box.
i have created another object objectA and assigned objectA=SelectedA.

Problem when i change combobox value value of objectA.Aid is also changed.

Thanks in advanced i need to avoid binding of objectA with SelectedA.

```
Vehicle dbvalue
 private Vehicle _selectedA;
 public Vehicle SelectedA
        {
            get { return _selectedA; }
            set
            {
                _selectedA = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedA");
            }
        }

 public partial class A
    {
        public int AID { get; set; }
        public string AName { get; set; }
    }

   <ComboBox 
                      DisplayMemberPath="AName"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedA.AID}"
                      SelectedValuePath="AName "/>
```

In viewmodel Class
i have used

```
dbvalue = SelectedA;
```

When i change combobox value dbvalue.AID is also changed.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippets. It'll help understand the problem. Having said that, if I've understood what you've described here you are describing the expected behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisF is this much code okay with you.

Comment: then remove the SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedA.AID}"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the behaviour of your `SelectedValue` binding to only update when the source changes.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedA.AID, Mode=OneWay}"
```

These are the other possible values for the Binding Mode lifted from the MSDN site:

- `TwoWay` updates the target property or the property whenever either the target property or the source property changes.
- `OneWay` updates the target property only when the source property changes.
- `OneTime` updates the target property only when the application starts or when   the DataContext undergoes a change.
- `OneWayToSource` updates the source property when the target property changes.
- `Default` causes the default Mode value of target property to be used.

[Original MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent of this problem, you can set it each property of object as follows:
     `objectA.AId = SelectedA.AId`
     `objectA.AName = SelectedA.AName`

Good Luck